# File sharing not working on iPad

Tags: file, ipad, sharing

I am trying to get file sharing to work on my app in iPad.  I've added UIFileSharingEnabled to the plist, I've queried the documents dir and written a file there (and verified it is there by looking at it through Organizer).  iTunes just refuses to display the file sharing info in the device's apps tab.  Does anyone know of any obscure step I might be missing, or some edge case that might be causing my problem?  I've tried all the rebooting, clean building avenues.

Comment: Is this a feature of the newest OS?  (The ability to retrieve documents from an application has been a shortcoming so far)

Comment: I don't know how new it is, but you can read about it on apple's docs linked from one of my other posts (here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995066/how-can-i-retrieve-files-from-an-ipad-development-tool-app )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what fixed this for me: I built an ad-hoc distribution and installed it on my iPad.  I believe once the app was installed/recognized as an actual "app" in itunes (versus something that shows up as a function of building through xcode), it was able to handle recognizing it as being able to share documents.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a sync of your iPad to iTunes. That did it for me.

Comment: Yeah, tried it and it didn't work. :(  Thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: You might also try installing your app through iTunes once instead of Xcode; I've heard of some folks having success that way.

Comment: is there a way to do that with a dev build, or do I need to create an adhoc build of it (so it shows up in the list of apps)?

Comment: I *think* you can do it with a dev build, but I haven't tried. I'd use 'build and archive' in Xcode to produce an .ipa for iTunes.